# CSS - Color is not changing

Tags: html, css

i am trying to fix a color of my TEXT color, its just WHITE so same color as background, dispite the fact its color is set for :#1a6eb6 and its set for same value in #submenu ul li .text I am prettz lost in it, can somebody help me with it?

My HTML:

```
  <span id="right">
    <ul>
    <li><span class="blue-arrow"></span><span class="newsheading"><a href="#">Gamesites má nový web ou jeeee!</a></span><span class="blueballoon">10</span><span class="balloon">10</span></li>
    <li><span class="blue-arrow"></span><span class="newsheading"><a href="#">Gamesites má nový web ou jeeee!</a></span><span class="blueballoon">10</span><span class="balloon">10</span></li>
    <li><span class="blue-arrow"></span><span class="newsheading"><a href="#">Gamesites má nový web ou jeeee!</a></span><span class="blueballoon">10</span><span class="balloon">10</span></li>
    <li><span class="blue-arrow"></span><span class="newsheading"><a href="#">Gamesites má nový web ou jeeee!</a></span><span class="blueballoon">10</span><span class="balloon">10</span></li>
    <li><span class="blue-arrow"></span><span class="newsheading"><a href="#">Gamesites má nový web ou jeeee!</a></span><span class="blueballoon">10</span><span class="balloon">10</span></li>
    </ul>
  </span>
```

My CSS:

```
#submenu{
    color: #1a6eb6;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width:780px;
}

#submenu ul {
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-left: 0px;         
}

#submenu ul li{
    list-style-position: inside;    /* Bodka v novom riadku vo vnutry */
    list-style-type: none;          /* bez bodky */  
    background-image: url("images/shop_menu_bg.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 38px;
    width: 187px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #1a6eb6;         
}

#submenu ul li:hover {
    background-image: url("images/shop_menu_bg_hover.png");
    width: 187px;
    height: 38px;             
}

#submenu ul li .text{
    color: #1a6eb6;
    display: inline-block;    /* aby sa dala rovnomerne posunut sipka a nie podla dlzky textu*/
    height: 31px;
    width:115px;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin-left: 5px;         
}

#submenu ul li .horizontal-arrow{
    background-image: url("images/horizontal_arrow.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 19px;
    width: 14px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 45px;
    vertical-align: middle;       
} 

#submenu ul li:hover .horizontal-arrow{
    display:none;         
}

#submenu ul li .vertical-arrow{
    background-image: url("images/vertical_arrow.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    display:none;
    height: 12px;
    width: 19px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 45px;         
} 

#submenu ul li:hover .vertical-arrow{
    display: inline-block;             
}
```

Comment: and where is `#submenu`  in that  html..??

Comment: And where is `text` used in the HTML?

Comment: You aren't utilizing a class of `.text` anywhere in your HTML example and there isn't any CSS in your example that sets the text to white in the first place. Try making a JSFiddle that shows your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be

```
<span class="submenu">
```

Answer (score 0):

That would never ever work. Due to the reason that the parent element of the list (ul) is having an id or right now submenu.

Now since you're having the CSS for the submenu, you can change your HTML to meet the requirements other than changing your whole CSS file.

```
<span id="submenu">
    <ul>
    <li><span class="blue-arrow"></span><span class="newsheading"><a href="#">Gamesites má nový web ou jeeee!</a></span><span class="blueballoon">10</span><span class="balloon">10</span></li>
    <li><span class="blue-arrow"></span><span class="newsheading"><a href="#">Gamesites má nový web ou jeeee!</a></span><span class="blueballoon">10</span><span class="balloon">10</span></li>
    <li><span class="blue-arrow"></span><span class="newsheading"><a href="#">Gamesites má nový web ou jeeee!</a></span><span class="blueballoon">10</span><span class="balloon">10</span></li>
    <li><span class="blue-arrow"></span><span class="newsheading"><a href="#">Gamesites má nový web ou jeeee!</a></span><span class="blueballoon">10</span><span class="balloon">10</span></li>
    <li><span class="blue-arrow"></span><span class="newsheading"><a href="#">Gamesites má nový web ou jeeee!</a></span><span class="blueballoon">10</span><span class="balloon">10</span></li>
    </ul>
  </span>
```

Please note the className of submenu wouldn't work because `#` isn't a className selector. That is an ID selector.

This won't work:

```
<span class="submenu"> <!-- creating the class, not the id -->
```